Unable to connect with my RDS database on azure pipeline
I am using MySQL workbench to connect with RDS database. Now i have modified my database to private subnet and also made public accessible to false. If i try to connect with workbench not working.
Like SSH bastion host its connecting. Through azure devops pipeline only i m deploying project into AWS. If i m trying to connect with my RDS database, getting this error Can't connect to MySQL server on 'falaina-iacm-db-iac-dev.c7xlfwj2inwm.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (10060)
Help me to resolve this.

What do you mean by "i m deploying project into AWS"? What are you deploying? Is it in the same VPC as the database? What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the database? Your DNS name for the database resolves to a public IP address on the Internet, which suggests that it is set to Publicly Accessible = Yes. Did you Apply the changes?

@JohnRotenstein, i m using azure devops pipeline and deploy my webapplication onto AWS. On the azure devops pipeline we have stages for doing deployment. In that stage, i will create a database for my application. while creating database i m getting the error "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'falaina-iacm-db-iac-dev.c7xlfwj2inwm.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (10060)". Regarding security group had inbound rules to allow all traffic with 0.0.0.0/0 and MySQL/Aurora port 3306 with 0.0.0.0.0/0. Since database should not be publicly accessible, i have made as No.

What resource is attempting to connect to the database? Is something in Azure attempting to connect to it, or does the pipeline deploy an EC2 instance that connects to the database? More information, please.

@JohnRotenstein,Through azure devops pipeline we will deploy resource like RDS and Ec2 instance onto AWS. For that we will use build agent machine in azure devops. For creating database in RDS,we will use connectionstring of MySQL and do it. when rds is created on private subnet and publicly accessible false, when trying to create database through azure devops using build agent, it show the error eventhough RDS security group rule is 0.0.0.0.0/0

What is trying to connect to the database, and from where? Is the connection attempt coming from Azure (on the Internet) or from something in the same VPC as the Amazon RDS database? What makes you think the connection attempt should work?

@JohnRotenstein,Trying to create database in RDS. For that, using build agent machine from azure devops and trying to connect amazon rds mysql  for creating database C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe -hsev.c7xlfwj2inwm..rds.amazonaws.com -uroot -paw13* . If RDS is in public accessible= yes and its public subnet, able to connect via build agent from Azure devops. If i restrict the rds public accessible to NO and made rds in private subnet, it says error (10060).

I  have added security group inbound rule also for RDS to allow access from anywhere 0.0.0.0/0

The behaviour you describe is correct. If the build agent that wishes to connect with the database is running outside of the VPC (eg in Azure), then it will not be able to connect to a database that is running in a private subnet.

@JohnRotenstein, Yes its not connecting. is there any way to connect database on that scenario?

No. You have placed it in a private subnet, which means it is not accessible from the Internet.
